# How to check for and create a shared (hidden) admin directory?

Tags: powershell, scripting, new-item

I have a few file servers that I want to create a path if it doesn't exist... Simple right? I thought so, BUT the path is along a hidden admin share.

Just when I think I am getting decent at scripting a simple problem trolls the $h#@$#@ out of me...

Here is the code I scratched out:

```
Cls
#check for fileshare
$servers = get-content C:\Temp\test.txt

forEach ($server in $servers) {
$shareTest = Test-Path "\\$Server\Share$\Test"

if($shareTest){
Write-Host "Path Exists on $server"
}
Else{
New-Item -Path "\\$Server\Share$\" -Name Test -ItemType Directory

Write-Host "Path Exists on $server"
}
}
```

I receive the error:

> New-Item : The path is not of a legal form.
>   At line:5 char:7

Presumably this is because there is a $ in the path. I am not sure how to escape it, or whatever voodoo I need to do to make it work...

This has cropped up a couple times in different scripts and I would like to clamp it off before I bleed out...

Thanks gang.

Comment: Your path syntax works for me on PowerShell v5. This could be a timing issue. Is this all of the code or just a simplified example? Try with a sleep statement for a few seconds before and after the `new-item` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into odd situations where the '$' was interpreted oddly via variable expansion.  You can get around this where it's problematic via string tokenization:

```
$server = 'hiyo'
'\\{0}\{1}' -f $server, 'share$'
```